# Git cloned laravel project won't migrate

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, homestead, laravel-5

I've recently cloned a Laravel project from Gitlab and Keep getting an error when trying to `php artisan migrate`.
Error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                       
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'blog.articles' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `articles` where `published` = 1)

[PDOException]                                                                             
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'blog.articles' doesn't exist
```

.env:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=UQ6ZJpBveXSQUC0q5lUzdnHb6qzwkLxo

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

database.php:

```
'default' => env('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql'),

// . . .

'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'blog'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

What is the cause of this problem?

P.S
I am trying to run the project from [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead).

---

**EDIT 1**

It seems, that some code that depends on the tables is run before migrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. As I expected, some custom code was running `before` migrations. The code was located in `Providers/` and commenting it out resolved the issue.